# MySQL joins and group columns

Tags: mysql

In the following situation i need to somehow group some columns into one. I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.id,b.id,c.id,d.id
FROM some_table AS a
LEFT JOIN some_table AS b ON ( a.id=b.parent_id )
LEFT JOIN some_table AS c ON ( b.id=c.parent_id )
LEFT JOIN some_table AS d ON ( c.id=d.parent_id )
WHERE a.id = '22'
```

Results in:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  a.id  |  b.id  |  c.id  |  d.id  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    22  |    24  |    25  |  null  |
|    22  |   381  |  null  |  null  |
|    22  |   418  |  2389  |  9841  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This is an category table populated with 220,000+ rows.

I need the last id (which is not NULL). So in this case i need (25,381,9841)

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

best result should be:

```
+------+
|   id |
+------+
|   25 |
|  381 |
| 9841 |
```

Comment: Please show us your expected result.  It's very difficult to guess what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See COALESCE(). That's all you need!

Comment: correct, thank you very much! changed the order a little bit to `COALESCE(f.id,e.id,d.id,c.id,b.id,a.id) as id`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the above answer, it seems like you need

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(d.id, c.id, b.id) AS 'id'
FROM some_table AS a
LEFT JOIN some_table AS b ON ( a.id=b.parent_id )
LEFT JOIN some_table AS c ON ( b.id=c.parent_id )
LEFT JOIN some_table AS d ON ( c.id=d.parent_id )
WHERE a.id = '22'
```

That would give you an output of

```
+------+------+
| a.id |   id |
+------+------+
|   22 |   25 |
|   22 |  381 |
|   22 | 9841 |
```